# Como Validar tiempo de vida de login Android

Tags: android, webservice, login

Tengo ya terminada mi app en android studio, solo que ahora necesito hacer como un tipo de validación, donde mi sesión en un determinando tiempo expire y mande un alert y me regrese a la ventana de mi Login.

Aclaro este mensaje de session expirada me lo mandan desde un webservices.

Les dejo código de mi Login.

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    //public Button login;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    private EditText userNameET , passWordET;
    String editTextUsername;
    String editTextPassword;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrol";
    ArrayList<Empresa> EmpresaArraylist = new ArrayList<Empresa>();
    final Context context = this;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Iniciar Sesion");
        actionBar.setSubtitle("ONControl");

        TextView textViewversionName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.VersionName);

        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            textViewversionName.setText("V"+"."+packageInfo.versionName);

        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        }

        int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Permiso Requerido");
                builder.setMessage("Permiso de Acceso a Localizacion");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        makeRequest();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            } else {
                makeRequest();
            }
        }


        userNameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        passWordET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        //Display Text control
        //final TextView statusTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        //Button to trigger web service invocation
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //Display progress bar until web service invocation completes
        //Button Click Listener
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (userNameET.getText().length() != 0 && userNameET.getText().toString().trim() != "") {
                    if (passWordET.getText().length() != 0 && passWordET.getText().toString().trim() != "") {
                        editTextUsername = userNameET.getText().toString().trim();
                        editTextPassword = passWordET.getText().toString().trim();
                        //statusTV.setText("");
                        //Create instance for AsyncCallWS
                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
                        AsyncCallWS_Login task = new AsyncCallWS_Login(settings.getString("ONControlWSURL", "").toString(),
                                                                           settings.getString("ONControlToken", "").toString(),
                                                                           settings.getInt("ONControlEmpresa", 0),
                                                                           settings.getString("ONControlUsuario", "").toString());
                        //Call execute
                        task.execute();
                    }
                    //If Password text control is empty
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ingresa Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    //If Username text control is empty
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ingresa Usuario",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }


        });

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
        AsyncEmpresa task = new AsyncEmpresa(settings.getString("ONControlWSURL", "").toString(),
                                             settings.getInt("ONControlEmpresa", 0),
                                             settings.getString("ONControlUsuario", "").toString());
        //Call execute
        task.execute();
    }

    protected void makeRequest() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_splash, menu);
        //tomar de datos de nuestra preferencia para mostrarlo en el edittex cuando reinicie app
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // action with ID action_refresh was selected
            case R.id.action_settings:
                GrabarUrl();
                break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class AsyncEmpresa extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList, ArrayList>
    {
        private String ONControlWSURL;
        private int ONControlZonaCliente;
        private String ONControlToken;
        private int ONControlEmpresa;
        private String ONControlUsuario;

        public AsyncEmpresa(String ONControlWSURL,
                            int ONControlEmpresa,
                            String ONControlUsuario)
        {
            this.ONControlUsuario = ONControlUsuario;
            this.ONControlWSURL = ONControlWSURL;
            this.ONControlEmpresa = ONControlEmpresa;
        }
        @Override
        protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params) {
            EmpresaArraylist = new ArrayList<Empresa>();
            webService O_WS = new webService(ONControlWSURL,
                                             ONControlZonaCliente,
                                             ONControlToken,
                                             ONControlEmpresa,
                                             ONControlUsuario);
            EmpresaArraylist=O_WS.Empresa();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList) {
            super.onPostExecute(arrayList);

            if(EmpresaArraylist.size()!=0){


               Spinner spiner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spBussinessType);
                ArrayAdapter<Empresa> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Empresa>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, EmpresaArraylist);
                spiner.setAdapter(adapter);
                spiner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putInt("ONControlEmpresa",EmpresaArraylist.get(position).getId());
                        editor.commit();


                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){}
                });

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ingresa Direccion de Servidor" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private class AsyncCallWS_Login extends AsyncTask<String,String,webService.STR_Resultado> {

        private String ONControlWSURL;
        private int ONControlZonaCliente;
        private String ONControlToken;
        private int ONControlEmpresa;
        private String ONControlUsuario;

        public AsyncCallWS_Login(String ONControlWSURL,
                                 String ONControlToken,
                                 int ONControlEmpresa,
                                 String ONControlUsuario)
        {
            this.ONControlUsuario = ONControlUsuario;
            this.ONControlWSURL = ONControlWSURL;
            this.ONControlToken = ONControlToken;
            this.ONControlEmpresa = ONControlEmpresa;
        }

        @Override
        //Make Progress Bar visible
        protected void onPreExecute() {
           dialog=new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setMessage("Loding...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected webService.STR_Resultado doInBackground(String... params) {
            webService.STR_Resultado O_ResultadoLogin = null;
            webService O_WS = new webService(ONControlWSURL,
                                             ONControlZonaCliente,
                                             ONControlToken,
                                             ONControlEmpresa,
                                             ONControlUsuario);

            O_ResultadoLogin = O_WS.Login(editTextUsername,
                                          editTextPassword);
            return O_ResultadoLogin;
        }

        @Override
        //Once WebService returns response
        protected void onPostExecute(webService.STR_Resultado Result) {
            super.onPostExecute(Result);
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("ONControlToken",Result.Token);
            editor.commit();

            settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorUsuario = settings.edit();
            editorUsuario.putString("ONControlUsuario",Result.UserName);
            editorUsuario.commit();

            if(Result.Valido == true) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gracias por Iniciar Sesion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrol.Menu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }else {

                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Datos Incorrectos," +
                        "Favor de Ingresar de Nuevo tus Datos",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void GrabarUrl(){
        try {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Ingresa la URL / IP  del Servidor");

//Creamos el input text y asignamos el tipo de EditText que     necesitamos
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI);
            builder.setView(input);

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
            input.setText(settings.getString("ONControlWSURL",""));

// Agregamos los botones de Guardar/Cancelar
            builder.setPositiveButton("Guardar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    //Creo Mi sharepreferens
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("ONControlWSURL",input.getText().toString());
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Datos Guardados",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    AsyncEmpresa task = new AsyncEmpresa(settings.getString("ONControlWSURL", "").toString(),
                            settings.getInt("ONControlEmpresa", 0),
                            settings.getString("ONControlUsuario", "").toString());
                    //Call execute
                    task.execute();

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("ERROR",ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Es importante aclarar lo siguiente: la notificación de expiración "te la envía" el webservice o "tienes que consultarla" en un webservice? Podemos confirmar eso?

Comment: Si requieres que sea en "tiempo real" podrías enviar el tiempo de vida de la sesión mediante el webservice en el proceso de "inicio de sesión" , e inmediatamente ejecutar un servicio que se encargue de el manejo de ese tiempo de vida. Aquí está la documentación de servicios en android: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html Si puedes manejarlo en la intención de apertura de cada una de las vistas, podrías enviar el tiempo de vida de la sesión mediante el webservice en el proceso de "inicio de sesión" y guardarlo mediante shared preferences, esto te obliga a que cada que s